# Display data in straight rows and aligned nicely through python

Tags: python

What to do now, please what to do now
How to append thanks

```
students.append(s1)
students.append(s1)
students.append(s1)
students.append(s1)
students.append(s1)
students.append(s1)
students.append(s1)
students.append(s1)
students.append(s1)
students.append(s1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `__str__` method to your student class:

```
class student:
def __init__(self, code, name, number):
    self.code = code
    self.name = name
    self.number = number

def __str__(self):
    return '\t'.join((self.code, self.name, self.number))

students = []
s1 = student("901", "Joh Doe", "123456")
s2 = student("902", "Mary Mount", "566665")
s3 = student("903", "David Lee", "394624")

students.append(s1)
students.append(s2)
students.append(s3)

for student in students:
    print student
```

Answer (score 0):

install [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) first: 
`pip install tabulate`

```
from tabulate import tabulate
class student:
    def __init__(self, code, name, number):
        self.code = code
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.stu = [self.code, self.name, self.number]

students = []
s1 = student("901", "Joh Doe", "123456")
s2 = student("902", "Mary Mount", "566665")
s3 = student("903", "David Lee", "394624")

students.append(s1.stu)
students.append(s2.stu)
students.append(s3.stu)

print(tabulate(students))
```

Comment: It doesn't work, i got this error: "TypeError: can only join an iterable"